# Issues accessing psql on mac OSX

Tags: macos, postgresql, heroku

I installed Postgres 9.4 a while back. I recently installed 9.6 via the enterprise method but ended up uninstalling it because I thought it was causing problems.

Now I'm trying to use heroku pg:push but am receiving errors. When I tried to resolve it I realized I cannot even access psql via the command line. The error I get is:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

When I run $ which psql the output is /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/psql which is where my installation is located. How can I fix this so heroku pg:push starts working again?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else looking at this, my 9.4 version was running on port 5433. I was able to temporarily fix the problem by creating an environment variable with `export PGPORT=5433`. That allowed psql to work, and in turn allowed my heroku pg:push to work as well.

I'm interested to hear how I can fix this in the long term.